# How to get Ltool by Martin et.al?

Tags: interplanetary

I am just starting work on dynamics of CRTBP. Over several papers I see that "Ltool" is used for trajectory design, But I am unable to find over internet. Can somebody help me to identfy how to download or buy(if not free)?

Comment: https://www.agi.com/home was [suggested to me](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27964/if-i-wanted-to-get-involved-in-space-exploration-what-should-could-i-do). I have yet to try it though, as I am still trying to understand more about material sciences, orbital mechanics and other things.

Comment: It is going to be hard to use advanced tools for three-body solution software without some DIY experience. If it turns out that you are really just starting, take a look at [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20590/12102) and then after that, [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27603/12102) and poke around this site in general looking for "cr3bp" and "halo orbit" for other interesting answers and questions.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this existing answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/3964/58), LTool is not public, but used internally at JPL. However, the [public description](http://www.ieec.cat/hosted/web-libpoint/abstracts/lo2.pdf) of the LTool package does list contact email addresses; so it may be possible to email and request a copy of the tool.

Comment: LTool was developed by the folks in Section 343 at JPL (reorganization might have changed that number since I left JPL) who jealously guard their software. They might give you information about how they approach the mechanics, but I seriously doubt they would export it. *Unless*...they now have something better, so it's probably worth a try.

Comment: @TomSpilker Thanks for the additional info! I figured if it wasn't already publicly available that it was probably closely guarded, but it never hurts to ask.

Comment: It's not so much about closely guarding. The main reason that they don't like to distribute their software is that they don't want to have to make it presentable, don't want to have to make it useable, don't want to have to document it, and don't want to have to answer questions about it from outside users.

Comment: Technically, since the development was done with government funds, NASA can request outside distribution of any software and JPL could not refuse on the basis of competitive advantage. However then JPL would counter with a requirement for funds from NASA for the cleanup, documentation, and support. That would probably be the end of the discussion right there.

Comment: @MarkAdler That I can understand for sure!

Comment: Are there any other softwares for cr3bp . I need to simulate for the orbits associated with the restricted problem. I know some software exists for bifurcation specifically.

Comment: @KarthiRamachandran [This paper](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a596277.pdf) refers to the use of MATLAB for cr3bp.