# Software (besides Ltool) to simulate CR3BP (three body) problems?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mathematics, software, three-body

Are there any other softwares for CR3BP *besides Ltool?* As I've learnt [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/29548/12102) Ltool is not generally available to the public. I would like to simulate three body orbits within the standard circular restricted three-body problem (CR3BP) scenario  as the first step and gradually move to other models like elliptical, bi-circular and quasi bi-circular etc.

I would be glad to know some 4 to 5 s/w's. Though I know some softwares like AUTO specifically for bifurcation, which I may concentrate on later part, I'm looking for something more basic to start with.

Comment: The question [What is a near rectilinear halo orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24019/12102) has some links to papers, and the answer there links to *two more papers*, each of which mentions some specific, potentially helpful software packages. I don't know if those are helpful to you or not, but have a look. If you do find something helpful, feel free to post an answer to your own question!

Comment: The CR3BP dynamics is a first order system with six equations, so any ODE  solver (ode45 MATLAB, python scipy ode) can simulate it. As far as I know, the issue with CR3BP has to be more with finding periodic orbits, invariant manifold of these, etc, where specific software such as AUTO is strongly recommended.

Comment: @Julio that is excellent advice. I'd left [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29547/how-to-get-ltool-by-martin-et-al?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment87173_29547) at the OP's previous question.